# Remove / hide the "All Apps" shortcut from the Start Menu --- or uninstall them totally

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, modern-ui, start-menu

This question has two parts:

1. I've Googled but cannot find anything about this. Is there a way to **make that "All Apps" section disappear completely from the Start Menu**? (The section to which I refer is labelled as #2 [here](https://4sysops.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/The-new-Start-menu-in-Windows-10-Technical-Preview.png).) *I kept coming across posts that addressed how to remove individual apps from that grouping - but that's not what I'm trying to do...*
2. Also, I'd honestly rather **uninstall all of those "Metro" apps altogether**. I found it quite surprising when I'd right-click on an app shortcut and "uninstall", it was only for that user. I found help online how to use PowerShell to remove them. But that wasn't too effective - in particular I remember the XBox just wouldn't go away. I ended up taking ownership of the folder that contains all of those *"lovely"* apps and renaming some of them with some prefix like "REMOVED___"... Is there a way to actually blow all of these away completely?

Comment: Use Classic Start Menu (part of [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/)) ;)

Comment: David, thank you. [I asked on the Classic Shell forums](http://www.classicshell.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=5123) if that is possible but their site admin just replied that it does not do that.

Comment: Really? You should be able to remove items from the start menu. In any case I don't see "All Apps" on the Windows 10 screenshots on their site http://www.classicshell.net/forum/download/file.php?id=2508 and http://www.classicshell.net/forum/download/file.php?id=2382. On Windows 7 it is called "Programs" and I can remove it from the menu if I want ...

Comment: It's lableled as #2 in [this "re-purposed" screenshot](https://4sysops.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/The-new-Start-menu-in-Windows-10-Technical-Preview.png)

Comment: Like I said it's **not** on the screenshots I posted ;) Classic menu **replaces** the normal Windows 10 menu and is configurable. Why not try it and see? You can always uninstall it if it doesn't work for you ...

Answer (score 1):

Part 1. Install [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/) open Settings then the Customize Start Menu tab. Drag Apps out of Current menu items into Available commands.

Part 2. Now they're hidden try to ignore them. Tweak Control Panel, Default Programs to replace where possible with programs you prefer.

[image: Classic Shell's Customize Start Menu tab]