# Disable all apps column in Windows 10 after anniversary update

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

The anniversary update added a column with all the programs/apps installed on my computer. How do I disable it?

This question is different from ["Can I enable the Windows 7 Start menu in Windows 10?"](https://superuser.com/questions/946674/can-i-enable-the-windows-7-start-menu-in-windows-10), as the user in that question wants the metro styled tiles to disappear, so only the most often used apps are shown. I want the exact opposite, as I like the Windows 10 tiles and I think they look better than the Windows 7 app list.

[image: With VS without all apps]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove / hide the “All Apps” shortcut from the Start Menu — or uninstall them totally](http://superuser.com/questions/970609/remove-hide-the-all-apps-shortcut-from-the-start-menu-or-uninstall-them?rq=1).  I had to manually edit this comment because the mark as duplicate attempted to mark this qustion as a duplicate of the wrong question for some reason,  Before you blindly vote be sure your selecting the correct question :-)

Comment: @Ramhound It is close for sure. However the other question wants to remove a button. I want to remove (most likely) the list the button leads to.    If I am correct, after the anniversary update, the button was removed and replaced by the list. I knew how to hide the all apps button, but not the list.

Comment: NOT a duplicate or either: http://superuser.com/questions/970609/remove-hide-the-all-apps-shortcut-from-the-start-menu-or-uninstall-them or http://superuser.com/questions/946674/can-i-enable-the-windows-7-start-menu-in-windows-10 ! Both of those relate to **Window 10** and the All Apps button on the start menu. This question asks how to remove the now permanently expanded All Apps section in **Windows 10 Anniversary**. Different problem, different OS!

Comment: @Ramhound So because the answer is the same the question, regardless of it's content, must also be the same? I'm afraid you're logic is flawed. Neither of those two questions describe the problem people are facing with the new Windows 10 Anniversary update so they are of ZERO use to anyone searching for that problem.

Comment: @PeteWiFi - Having a single question with a single excellent answer, is better than, having multiple questions, with similar answers all suggesting the same general idea IMO

Comment: @Ramhound I completely disagree... people search for the problem they are having... not for OTHER problems with the SAME solution...

Comment: @inverse - There are no close votes currently, so it doesn't matter what I think, people don't agree with me.  So I will be removing my previous comments, except the "possible duplicate" comment, since they are not longer relevant.

Comment: Thanks for this question and it's absolutely abhorrent that M$ has given us no way to keep the start menu we love.

Comment: @ChaimEliyah, yes - it is horrible that after an update the start menu is changed and settings are either removed and/or interpreted differently. I used to have something that was close to Windows7 (no "ALL" aps, unless I clicked on an ALL apps button - and I accepted small "buttons" land (should tiles). I am so sick of MS changing this all the time. They never learn. Maybe they want us to quit windows for something else. "Sigh!" - One question, duplicate questions - it is windows - there is never one solution. I am grateful for multiple attempts to describe issues. Sometimes just what I need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you see is the [new start menu of Windows 10 Version 1607. Here MS placed the programs groups (A-Z) on the left side](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/04/22/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14328-for-pc-and-mobile/).

[image]

> We have merged the most used apps list and the All apps list into a
>   single view and elevated it to the top level of the UI to reduce
>   clicking and scrolling. You can now access all your apps with one
>   click on the Start menu. We have also moved important functionality
>   such as Power, Settings, and File Explorer so that they are always
>   visible in the left rail in the Start menu, and updated the Recently
>   added section so that it will now show 3 entries instead of just 1,
>   and can be expanded to see the entire list of new apps.

**In V1607 (Build 14393) there is no way to change this.**

Starting with [Build 14942](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/10/07/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14942-for-pc/) of the Creators Update for Windows 10 (which will be released in March/April 2017), there is an option in the settings app to disable the app list `Hide app list in Start menu`:

[image]

Now the list is gone:

[image] [image]

So you have to install the latest Insider Build or wait until 2017 when Microsoft releases the update to the public.

Comment: If you monitor your registry modification while changing settings, there's a chance you can find it's hidden registry key.

Comment: Excellent answer! I will award the bounty as well as soon as I can in 6 hours :)

Answer (score 3):

The only way I have found to "hide" it is by enabling a full screen start menu. Then an 'all apps' icon will appear on the left under 'expand' and 'pinned tiles'. It's annoying in full screen mode but I don't want the list either, I would just like the icon back.

[image: all apps icon instead of list]

Comment: Speaking to Windows tech support...there is not a way to remove/change the list and go back to an icon. You can change the transparency of the start menu, so I will be using a full screen transparent start menu, as to not see the annoying list

Comment: Thanks. You get an upvote for best alternative solution :)