# Windows 10 Start Menu Different Between Builds?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1607, windows-10-v1511

The first image is from Windows 10 v1511 (Build 10586.218), and the "All apps" menu item is tucked into the lower left corner, out of sight & mind.
[image]

This image is from a Surface Pro 4 running v1607 (Build 14393.321). The All Apps menu is taking up a ton of real estate and not contributing anything to society. How can I move it down to the lower corner like in the green start menu above?
[image]

Comment: "How can I move it down to the lower corner like in the green start menu above? " - You can't.  Microsoft found that people didn't understand, the hamburger icon, so they basically removed it.  There are numerous questions on this site that ask about this behavior by the way.  The answer to those existing questions is basically the same, you have to use a program like Classic Shell, or one of its many alternatives.  They have also removed it from all future UWP they might release.  There are exceptions to when it will exist.

Comment: [Remove / hide the “All Apps” shortcut from the Start Menu — or uninstall them totally](http://superuser.com/questions/970609/remove-hide-the-all-apps-shortcut-from-the-start-menu-or-uninstall-them)

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the explanation. I'd read the question you linked already and was dissatisfied that the poster accepted "use a 3rd party app" as an answer. However, since you explain that it can't be done due to a design change by Microsoft, I get it now and will go ahead with the 3rd party solution. Thanks!

Comment: I honestly forget where I learned about the loss of the hamburger button.  I personally think that button was interface gold.

Comment: update to the latest Insider Build or what when the RS2 update gets released in 2017, here you can hide it: http://superuser.com/a/1132569/174557

Comment: @magicandre1981 Now THAT Is what I was hoping to see! Thanks for bringing this update to my attention, I've got the Surface signed up for Insider Builds now.